# What is this metal "brick" doing under the stone veneer of a fireplace?

Tags: fireplace, brick, stone

I'm in the process of removing a stone veneer from a fireplace in our basement, as there's white brick underneath that I want to expose. This fireplace is identical to an upstairs one that has the same nice, white brick and I want this fireplace to match. I just started chipping off the corner and am surprised by how easily the stone veneer and mortar come off.

But as I got further, I found a strange brown metallic "brick" thingy sandwiched between the stone veneer and white brick. I have no idea what it is or what it's for or how easily it can be removed. If I'm wanting to remove the stone and leave the brick, should I also remove whatever this metal "brick" is, or is that likely in place for the sake of the white brick?

Here's a photo, which shows the stone veneer, metallic "brick" circled in red, and the white brick underneath:

[image]

Comment: Are you _certain_ it's metal? Will a magnet stick to it? I've seen glazed bricks that _look_ metallic, but are definitely clay on the inside. No idea why they'd have spent extra money for fancy glazed blocks inside, but maybe it's what they had on hand.

Comment: I haven't tried the magnet trick. I suppose it's possible that it's some kind of glazed brick, but I was tapping it with a pick ax last night, and it sure felt / sounded like some metallic substance.

Comment: The stone veneer may well not be original, @FreeMan. I'd leave it in place at least until you expose the whole brick structure - there might be a pattern going on.

Comment: I was thinking that, too, @Ecnerwal, just forgot to say it. ;)

Comment: Yes, @Ecnerwal - correct! I'm 99% sure the stone veneer is not original. The white brick underneath matches the upstairs fireplace and is identical to the white brick used on the exterior of the house. I'm a little dumfounded as to why the previous owners covered it up with the stone.

Comment: I've seen bronze bricks (magnet would not stick) used as places to put a survey reference mark (since you can center-punch a precise location on the surface) or the like, but not typical in houses. Could be one of those salvaged from somewhere as an accent feature...?